# JQuery and PHP Infinite Scrolling Help

Tags: php, jquery, infinite-scroll

I'm having a problem with my infinite scrolling. As I scroll down, it loads the next items fine but it keeps sending those items. I've been using this jquery to give it a unique id because I have ordered the items with mysql with an algorithm:

```
$("#image-list li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('id', index);
});
```

and inorder to label the newly given items from an external php file, I have to use this code in the file as well.

To send the information about the items given, I've been using this jquery:

```
function last_db_item_function() 
 { 

    var ID=$(".db-item:last").attr("id");
    $('div#last-db-item-loader').html('<img src="loading.gif" height="30px" />');
    $.post("index.php?action=get&last_db_item="+ID,

    function(data){
        if (data != "") {
        $(".db-item:last").after(data);         
        }
        $('div#last-db-item-loader').empty();
    });
 };  

 $(window).scroll(function(){
    if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
       last_db_item_function();
    }
 });
```

but the problem is that it does not seem to work. Which I mean it doesn't not gather that last item id from the newly parsed php file. To parse the php I've been doing this:

```
$last_db_item = $_GET['last_db_item'];
$action = $_GET['action'];      

if($action != "get")
{
 .... Code Here....
}else{
 include ('secondimages.php');

}
```

So my question is, why does this seem to go on forever?

Comment: i think because the window.height is always increasing when u append data in it try debugging the expression $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())

Comment: @G molvi I dunno if I explained it very well but I hope this makes sense, why does the last_db_item_function() Function update when the secondimages.php is parsed? it says on the previous number permanently 
e.g. the first last number was 6 and it when the php is parsed, the number does not update to 12 or whatever it remains on 6.

Comment: just to make sure, the load request is fires just fine, but the returned data is always the same post? Please check with Firebug (unter net or console) what informations are delivered via the POST Header (ether its always the same ID that send, or the PHP Script sends the same data regardless of the ID)

Comment: So is the page forever getting new elements, or is the problem that it's getting the same item over and over?

Comment: what do you have in secondimages.php i dont think it contains a recursive call but just double check

Comment: I've fixed it. You were right, there was no recursive call! :L I'm a little stupid at times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're never assigning a new ID to the new elements when you append them to the list. The first snippet you have either needs to be called after every new element is added, or similar code needs to be applied to that one element when you add it (unless it's coming back in the php, at which point we'd need to know more about what you're returning)